# How do I call a function in C# that appears later in the file?

Tags: c#

How do I call a function in C# in `static main()`?

```
class Conditional
{
    static void if_else();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int select;
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for if_else");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for Switch");
        select = Console.Read();
        if (select == 1)
        {
           if_else(); // I have an error here
        }
    }

    static void if_else()
    {
        bool test = true;
        if (test)
            Console.WriteLine("if condition executed");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Else condition executed");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code as code. You can do so by putting 4 spaces in front of each code line

Comment: Why do you have `static void if_else();` near the top of your code? Just get rid of that...

Comment: Error: CS0501 'UserQuery.Conditional.if_else()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Comment: Error  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Class_Practice_Console.Conditional.if_else()' and 'Class_Practice_Console.Conditional.if_else()'

Comment: C# is not C.  No need for forward declarations in this case.

Comment: @TamirVered why did you add the .NET tag to this question, a year after it was closed? This question is about the C# syntax, so not .NET-related at all.

Answer (score 2):

That's the right way to define a function. However, I think that your problem is that you define the same function twice.

Try removing the third line and see if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void if_else();
```

The above line is not required for C#, and please remove it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
static void if_else();
```

is redundant.

The code

```
static void if_else()
{
    bool test = true;
    if (test)
        Console.WriteLine("if condition executed");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Else condition executed");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

defines the function and this is enough. Unlike many other languages (C, C++, etc...), in C# you don't need to declare the functions at the beginning of the code.

By the way, you should want to join the declaration and the assignment of `select`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for if_else");
Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for Switch");
int select = Console.Read();
```

Unlike C, in C# you don't have to declare the variables at the beginning of a scope, and this way the code is way more readable.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you don't need to, nor should you declare methods like you do in C or C++.

So remove the following line.

```
static void if_else();
```

I don't know exactly what error you got, but it's probably the ambiguity between the two method definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Firstly, remove this line from the code.

```
static void if_else();
```

You don't have to declare function prototypes in C#.

Secondly, `Console.Read` returns you the character code entered. Typing `1` in at the prompt will not lead to `if_else` being called. You'd have to change your line to:

```
if (select==((int)'1'))
```

to get this to work as you're hoping.